# Increase openfire memory to larger values

Tags: java, performance, memory, heap-memory, openfire

We use OpenFire for XMPP messages. We have some memory issues(OutOfMemoryError), and therefor we would like to increase memory. I know how to increase memory using VM options and we were able to increase memory to 1.5Gb. but larger values do not seem supported

We use a 32bit VM, since it appears 64bit VM's are not supported on OpenFire

My question: Is there anyone out there that was able to increase OpenFire memory to larger then 1.5GB values? if so, please learn me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/27552), add a following line in  `/etc/sysconfig/openfire`

```
OPENFIRE_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m"
```

I am afraid that you cannot get more than 1.4 to 1.6 GB on 32bit machine for heap allocation. You can check this article from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit).

Comment: correct, we use this, however you cannot enter values larger then 1.5GB. otherwise OpenFire will not start. which seems strange because 32bit vm's should support up to about 3GB

Comment: And following options might also help: INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS="-Xms128m -Xmx2048m" or  DAEMON_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx2048m"

Comment: yes. it gives an error as soon as you enter values larger then 1.5GB

Comment: this error to be precise: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cbKWO.png it is just strange that 1.5GB is the limit, why not 3 as you would expect on 32bit systems

Comment: I am afraid that 1.5GB is a max according to oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit. I updated the answer.

Comment: well, I'll be damned, you are correct. I'll start a new question to ask how to get openfire to work with a 64bit JVM. thanks for the answer